# ipad browser crash after loading images using kinetic js

Tags: javascript, ipad, kineticjs

I am using kinetics API for creating images,i pad browser is crashing on loading some images  i think the problem with the image objects,did any one face this problem before? please help.

Comment: First i am storing image objects in array and then using array to display one at a time on kinetic layer by providing navigation,on loading these images i pad browser is crashing,images are loading fine in desktop i am getting problem in i pad,please reply if any one faced this problem before ,thank you.

Comment: where is the code to look at?? A fiddle would be best

Answer (score 0):

try to clear layer and stage cache memory before create, if it already used(created). like this.

```
layer.removeChildren();
layer.clearCache();
layer.clear();
layer.destroyChildren();
layer.destroy();

stage.removeChildren();
stage.clearCache();
stage.clear();
stage.destroyChildren();
stage.destroy();
```